# how to retrieve data into text area based on selected option using foreach loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

I am having trouble retrieving data from database into text area based on dropdown list option that is selected, I've tried foreach but it didn't help.  All items will pop not only the one I want.

here is my php code:
vispage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$title = "hadeeth";
include_once ("header.php");
include 'connect.php';


//STEP 1: CREATE THE QUERY

$query = "SELECT * FROM `search`";

//STEP 2: RUN THE QUERY
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$hadeeth = array();

//STEP 3: RETRIEVE VALUES FROM RESULT
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$hadeeth[$row['name']] = array(
 'name'=>$row['name'],
 'short'=>$row['short']
 );

}
?>
```

html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="had">
<form name="det" action="vispage.php" method="POST">
<label for="hadeath">
Select Title of the Hadeath</label>
<select name="header">

                <?php foreach($hadeeth as $i) {?>
<option value="1"><?php echo $i['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select><br><br>
<a 
type="submit" name="det" class="btn btn-default" value="view details" 
    role="button">det</a></p>

<label for="a">tree :</label><br>
<textarea name="tree" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
</form>
</div>

</div>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: You want the textarea contents to change based on which item in the dropdown is selected?

Comment: @jaime yes I do ......

Comment: That is going to require the use of javascript. Specifically, look into jQuery. You're also going to have to have different option values in the dropdown to have any effect on the textarea.

Comment: @jaime yes all option values are retrieved from database as well as content

Comment: In your code, every `<option>` has a value of 1

Comment: Does `name` attribute of the `search` table unique? Does the form submit to the same page? i.e this is all the code of `vispage.php`?

Comment: thank you I have solved the problem using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do few steps:

- HTML Form : add event of `onchange` in drop down box
- Get selected value on event and send to `PHP` file via `jQuery` request
- PHP file : receive variable and get related data from database using `Query`
- send back in `json` encoded
- In `jQuery`, receive that output and decode in `json` and show in textarea

You need to use jQuery for `onchange` event

```
$('select[name=header]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'file-name.php',
        data : {selectedValue:value},
        dataType : 'json',
        success:function(response){
            $('textarea[name=tree]').html(tree);
        }
    });
});
```

Now you need to update your `PHP` file according.